# Hide hours in FullCalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

Today I downloaded FullCalendar.

The issue is that i want to use the plugin for a calendar that doesn't need hours. The events last all day long. Is it possible to hide the "hour" column in the "day" tab?

Answer (score 3):

Very simple use

```
, allDayDefault: true
```

after the header section in your fullcalnedar script.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the 'basicDay' view and set 'allDayDefault' as true:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,today,next',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
        },
        allDayDefault: true,
    })
});
```

With this configurations, the event will set as all day by default. And the views ',basicWeek' ans 'basicWeek' shows only the day, without the hours.

See the results:
[image: Month tab]

[image: Week tab]

[image: Day tab]

See more at the FullCalendar documentation: [FullCalendar Docs](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/).